# Converting Icon object to and from byte[] causes quality loss

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, type-conversion, icons

I am making a WPF app where `Image` have an `ImageSource` coming from an `Icon` object.

To save it on disk, I convert them to a `byte[]`, and the getter for the `ImageSource` convert the `byte[]` back into an `ImageSource`.

Problem, when doing it, the result look plain wrong, only a few colors seem to survive.

Here is a complete WPF solution that lets you see for yourself how horrible it looks:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="POCicon.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POCicon"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="{Binding WithConversion}" MaxHeight="32" MaxWidth="32" Stretch="Fill" ></Image>
        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding NoConversion}" MaxHeight="32" MaxWidth="32" Stretch="Fill" ></Image>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C# ViewModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace POCicon
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        private System.Drawing.Icon Icon;
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            Icon= System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
        }
        public ImageSource WithConversion
        {
            get
            {
                byte[] byteArray;
                using (MemoryStream serializer = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    Icon.Save(serializer);
                    byteArray = serializer.ToArray();
                }
                using (MemoryStream deserializer = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
                {
                    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                    image.BeginInit();
                    // image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat; //totally useless unfortunately
                    image.StreamSource = deserializer;
                    image.EndInit();
                    return image;
                }
            }
        }

        public ImageSource NoConversion
        {
            get
            {
                var imgSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(Icon.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
                return imgSource;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix this method, or to get the desired result going another route? The requirement is that it has to be an `Icon` object at some point, and ending up being a `byte[]`.

Thanks a lot

Comment: (Edit: this is a reply to a comment that was deleted) Yes, I had tried it too. just put it in the solution I wrote above, and result look the same, there is a loss of quality, but I don't understand where it comes from.

Comment: When converting Icon to ImageSource, no problem, but I need the byte[] to save them on disk.

Comment: Can't you first create a BitmapSource by CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon, and then encode it to a byte array?

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to try. Do you know how to go from the BitmapSource to the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `Icon.Save()`, use `Icon.ToBitmap()` to create a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` from the Icon, and save that:

```
var icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(
    @"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\dotPeek\v1.1\Bin\dotpeek32.exe");
var bitmap = icon.ToBitmap();

byte[] buffer;

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Alternatively, create the `byte[]` after converting to BitmapSource:

```
var icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(
    @"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\dotPeek\v1.1\Bin\dotpeek32.exe");
var bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
    icon.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));

byte[] buffer;

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    encoder.Save(memoryStream);
    buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

---

Comment: Indeed. Your solution solved my problem. Chosen answer.

Comment: Please also note the alternative using icon.ToBitmap.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, Clemens!

Comment: For future readers, I compared the two methods suggested by Clemens performance-wise. I went from a single Icon, converted to a byte[], and back to an ImageSource. The first method(Icon.ToBitmap()) takes 2 milliseconds, with an intermediary byte[1620]. The second method (Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(…)) takes 52 milliseconds, with antermediary byte[1776]. Seeing them both on screen, I don't notice a difference in definition or colors.